# Reset positions from Jquery UI Sortable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, reset

I am using sortable from Jquery UI. Each time I get the value from resultPos, it gives me the last move, but rememebr the last order. I need to reset it.

For example, I have 3 elements:

```
Move 3rd element to 2nd position: end=1&end=3&end=2
Again ...
Move 3rd element to 2nd position: end=1&end=2&end=3
Again ...
Move 3rd element to 2nd position: end=1&end=3&end=2
```

I need to have something that return to me the following:

```
Move 3rd element to 2nd position: end=1&end=3&end=2
Again ...
Move 3rd element to 2nd position: end=1&end=3&end=2
Again ...
Move 3rd element to 2nd position: end=1&end=3&end=2
```

This is my code:

```
$( ".sortableChip" ).sortable({
        revert: true,
        containment: "#carousel",
        axis: "x",
        items: 'li.edited',
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        placeholder: 'draggin-space',
        start: function(event, ui) { 
             var startPos = $('.sortableChip').sortable('serialize',{ key: 'start'});
        },
        sort: function(event, ui) {
            ui.item.addClass('draggin');
            $('.remove-chart').hide();
        },
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var resultPos = $('.sortableChip').sortable('serialize',{ key: 'end'});
            ui.item.removeClass('draggin');
        }
    });
```

Comment: This site http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-how-do-i-reset-to-the-original-positions-of-a-sortable-list-using-the-sortable-method does not help me :(

Answer (score 3):

every item in the jquery UI sortable is an LI, there are a few ways you can do it, one way is to to save a variable that has the sortable list contents when the page initially loads like in the document ready part. all its doing is rearranging the order of li tags that are inside of the ul tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){


         $('#link').click(function(){

            //this will empty out the contents of the ul
            $('.sortableChip').html('');
            /*this will replace the contents of the ul with 
            contents that were caputred 
            */
            $('.sortableChip').html(reset);

        });

    });

    var reset = $('.sortableChip').html();
    /*this is here at the bottom because you want to everything that is created     
    dynamically with jquery or javascript to be captured also.
    */
</script>
```

all you are basically doing is returning the right settings once the link is clicked and thats it, you actually don't need this line `$('.sortableChip').html('');
 but I put it here so you know that its being emptied out and replaced

if they need to be sorted based on what you click you would save the states you want tohave as variables like reset and simply clear the contents and load the variables based on what the user clicks

Comment: Thanks Jesse for answer, but is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Ok sorry about that I misunderstood the question, do you have a jsbin link or something like that I can see?